# Почему html не переноситься из src в dist?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Имеется такой `webpack config`,

```js
//dependencies

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

//plugins

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
 entry: './src/js/index.js',
 output: {
  path: __dirname + '/dist',
  publicPath: '/',
  filename: 'bundle.js'
 },
 devServer: {
  contentBase: './dist',
 },
 module: {
  rules: [
   {
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [
     {
      loader: 'html-loader',
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   filename: 'index.html',
   template: 'src/template/index.html'
  })
 ]
}
```

По идее `HtmlWebpackPlugin` должен перенести `index.html` в `dist` папку, но этого не происходит.

Структура файлов такая

```
-webpack.config.js
-src
--template
---index.html
-dist
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "sss",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "sss",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "create-it.studio",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "pug-html-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "webpack": "^4.39.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: покажите файл `config/index.js`

Comment: Ваш конфиг никаких подозрений не вызывает. Какой командой вы билдите?

Comment: @Дмытрык, он пустой, туда нужно что-то записывать?

Comment: @sneas, добавил package.json

Comment: а, так вы не билдите. Вы запускаете сервер. Странно что папка dist вообще создаётся. По идеи не должна.

Comment: добавьте `"build": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js"` в скрипты вебпка. Команда `build` будет создавать то что будет уходить на прод.

Comment: сорри в комментарии выше `webpack` можно использовать, а не `webpack-cli`. Уже поправил.